# Трудности с RecyclerView после обновления до API 27

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-layout-inflater

Всё работало хорошо, пока не обновила в gradle Sdk до 27. В логах говориться 'ViewHolder views must not be attached when created'. Но параметр attachToRoot в моём LayoutInflater и так установлен в значении 'true'. Пожалуйста, объясните, в чем может быть моя ошибка? 
Logcat:

```
06-02 11:40:15.669 22801-22801/com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame, PID: 22801
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6687)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**:

```
public class GameTableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameTableAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private ArrayList<Litera> literas;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Button> adapterItems;
    private View mainView;
    private int itemSize;

    public GameTableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Litera> literas, Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap, int itemSize) {
        this.literas = literas;
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
        this.context = context;
        this.adapterItems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.itemSize = itemSize;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.but_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        char mChar = literas.get(position).getCharValue();
        holder.item.setText(String.valueOf(mChar));
        if (this.hashMap.containsKey(position) && (hashMap.get(position)!=null)) {
            setImg(hashMap.get(position), holder.item);
            holder.item.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return literas.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Button item;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            item = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            item.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(itemSize, itemSize));
            item.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,(float)itemSize/2);
            adapterItems.add(item);
        }

    }

    public Litera getItem(int id) {
        return literas.get(id);
    }

    public Button getButItem(int id) {
        return adapterItems.get(id);
    }

    public View getMainView() {
        return mainView;
    }

    public void animateItem(int id) {
        adapterItems.get(id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        adapterItems.get(id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

В **Fragment**:

```
    recyclerView = (TouchableRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_chars);
...

public void setUpAdapter() {
        numberOfColumns = col;
        int itemSize = screenWidth / numberOfColumns;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), numberOfColumns));
        adapter = new GameTableAdapter(getActivity(), literas, hashMapAllColors, itemSize);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

**TouchableRecyclerView.java**

```
public class TouchableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public TouchableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean performClick() {
        return super.performClick();
    }

}
```

В **xml**:

```
<com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame.widgets.TouchableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_chars"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tapped_word"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:longClickable = "false">

    </com.bestworldgames.bestwordgame.widgets.TouchableRecyclerView>
```

**but_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_color_1"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false">
</Button>
```

> Пока могу сказать, что ошибка возникает после работы конструктора
>   `public ViewHolder(View itemView)` и перед методом
>   `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position)`

Comment: Ну... Тут надо локализовать проблему. Попробуйте по очереди комментировать разные куски кода в адаптере/холдере/фрагменте и смотреть не пропадёт ли ошибка. Тогда можно будет понять куда смотреть и, возможно, что делать. Пока что причина не видна.

Comment: [Юрий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1), да уже как раз этим занимаюсь..) Спасибо, обязательно напишу если локализую проблему.

Comment: Была такая проблема недавно, но не помню как решил :-/ код вроде совпадает `parent=false`, но попробуйте написать не просто `ViewHolder`, а `GameTableAdapter.ViewHolder` где позволит. Навскидку это единственное различие между нашими кодами ). Помню ошибка была в

Comment: В `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: [Jarvis_J](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195187/jarvis-j), спасибо! Сработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [Jarvis_J](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195187/jarvis-j) за [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837110/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81-recyclerview-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE-api-27#comment1340894_837110) моей проблемы!!!